# Temperature of my 8600GS graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, temperature

How can I see the temperature of my 8400GS graphics card?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) will tell you everything you ever wanted to know about your video card:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With EVGA percision it will display the temp on your systembar and *Ingame. Works with most all 8+ Gen Gpu's . you need the latest forceware drivers for it to work. it works with my Nvidia 8200M G IGP on Windows Vista 64 and now on Windows 7 64.  So im sure it will work fine for you.